# ViewPager is skipping a fragment when I take the picture or accept the permission

Tags: java, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I'm making a project in viewpager2. However, in one of the fragments I ask for the camera's permission and take the photo, and after I take it with the cell phone camera, it should show the photo in the fragment. However, when I go back to the fragment it goes to the next page automatically and without any error. Is there any way to control this and not let it jump until the user clicks the button?

```
class ViewActivity : BaseActivity() {

   private lateinit var binding: ActivityView
   private lateinit var adapter: PagerAdapter

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

      adapterViewPager()
      goToNextPage()
      goToBackPage()
   }

   private fun adapterViewPager(){
      adapter = ViewAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

      adapter.addFragment(HelloWordFragment())
      adapter.addFragment(TakePictureFragment())
      adapter.addFragment(LoginFragment())
      adapter.addFragment(ConfirmEmailFragment())

      binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter
   }

   private fun goToNextPage(){
      binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(binding.viewPager.currentItem + 1)
   }
 
   private fun goToBackPage(){
      binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(binding.viewPager.currentItem - 1)
   }
}
```

PagerAdapter in java

```
public final class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

   private final List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<>() 

   ViewAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Lifecycle lf){
      super(fm, lf)
   }

   public Fragment createViewPager(int position){
      retirn fragList.get(position)
   }

   public void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
      fragList.add(fragment)
   }
}
```

Fragment da foto

```
class TakePictureFragment : Fragment() {
   
   private lateinit var binding : FragmentTakePicture

   override fun onCreateView(
      inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View {
      binding = FragmentTakePicture.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
      return binding.root
   }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

      next()
   }

   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE -> {...}
                REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE -> {...}
            }
      }
   }

   private fun next(){
      binding.buttonNext.setOnClickListener {
         parent.goToNextPage()
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the way you're managing the navigation between the fragments.
First of all, this, in ViewActivity

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

  adapterViewPager()
  goToNextPage()
  goToBackPage()}
```

here you're invoking sequentially both the function to navigate back and forth, as soon as the Activity gets created(onCreate), is there a reason for that?

Then, in TakePictureFragment there's no need to wrap the button listener in a next() function, try this:

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

  binding.buttonNext.setOnClickListener {
     parent.goToNextPage()
  }}
```